# Not able to deploy Kubeflow pipelines to GKE cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, google-cloud-ai, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I have created a GKE cluster according to the requirements (https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/pipelines/docs/configure-gke-cluster) of the Kubeflow Pipelines as following:

- 3 nodes with at least 4GB ram and two CPUs
- Custom service account with roles: logging.logWriter, monitoring.metricWriter, monitoring.viewer, storage.objectViewer

When trying to select the cluster on the Kubeflow Pipelines (from Marketplace) configuration, it says "Insufficient OAuth scopes".

I thought maybe I overlooked an important steps, so I tried creating a new cluster from the Kubeflow Pipelines configuration page. When trying to select this cluster, it still says "Insufficient OAuth Scopes".

Are there more roles that need to be added to the service account?

Comment: Hello. As there are multiple ways shown in the documentation could you provide the exact steps you've followed? Have you used the script to create this service account? Have you used this account when creating your `GKE` cluster in `Nodes` -> `node-pool`-> `Security` section?  Do you have any `node-pools` in this cluster that **do not** use this service account?

Comment: I followed the steps for granular access, the only difference is we use terraform to do it. https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/pipelines/docs/configure-gke-cluster#configure-service-account. Also, the service account is listed under Nodes->node-pool->Security.

Note that the same thing happens if you let the Kubeflow Pipelines setup (from marketplace) create the cluster for you. Steps to reproduce: Let the setup create the cluster, reload the setup-page. You will now see that the cluster created is ineligible.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you need to configure oauth-scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform for the node pool in addition to the service account for granular access. The oauth-scope sort of enables access to "everything", but access is restricted based on the IAM roles for the service account.

The documentation could have been clearer on this.